# How to create subdomain on aws and point that from godaddy dns domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have followed the below link instructions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-routing-traffic-for-subdomains.html

1. The server is nodejs it is running on AWS server 80 port.
2. I have a domain on GoDaddy and want to point that nodejs server as a subdomain from GoDaddy DNS.
3. Follow the link above and set up the things accordingly.
4. Using only node server neither Apache or Nginx

but nothing helps me to get out of the issue

Comment: Why this negative feedback on the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your domain is `example.com` and you have it on GoDaddy, follow the steps below:

1. Create a public hosted zone on Route53. This will create a record-set of type NS with 4 values.
2. On GoDaddy, create a record-set of type NS called `subdomain.example.com` pointing to all 4 names you got from the 1st step.

Comment: Hi @Azize did the same thing on my AWS and GoDaddy server but it does not work for me. My main domain is using the https and my subdomain is running on 80 port so, is it creating any issue. Thanks :)

Comment: DNS does not handle port, just names, so if you have an issue with redirect from one port to another one, it is not related to subdomain from GoDaddy to Route53, it is something with the service you are hosting on AWS.

Comment: I'm not using any port to configure it just uses the above steps, Som of the user on StackOverflow says to configure the virtual host on Apache or Nginx. However, i have configured the same on Nodejs.

Comment: Exactly, this is an issue with your `nodejs`, not with DNS subdomain. First make sure your subdomain is working fine, than you can address the port issue.